# Open URL and place it to a string

Tags: python, regex

`filehandle = urllib.urlopen(myurl)`

Because of the fact that I want to `regex` the `filehandle` afterwords I need to transform the filehandle from an object to a string. 
How can I make the webpage code to be stored in a string?

Comment: Also if you want to extract data, don't use regex, use a proper html parser like `lxml`

Comment: @JakobBowyer Why should I do it with `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup`. Isn't it more easy with the `regex` way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why accept Anuj, my answer is clearer and provides a document link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
page = filehandle.read()
```

You can also iterate over it, like:

```
lines = []
for line in filehandle:
    lines.append(line)
```

For extracting data, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://www.lxml.de).

Comment: Please don't name your variables after builtin types.

Comment: `string` is not a type. `str` is.

Comment: The idea of calling it `string` is non descriptive though. Someone who has to maintain this code might not know what string was or where it came from.

Comment: you don't need to call `.readlines()` as this reads the whole file into memory anyway, you can just use `for x in file:` as it reads each line when required.

Comment: If you are iterating directly over the file object, you don't need to append to a list, because then you are just doing exactly what `readlines()` does

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, sir! But fh is a file instance. Read it once and you can't do that again. A list is a list.

Comment: Just use it as you iterate it!

Comment: What if you need to use it again? i.e. Iterate twice?

Comment: If you need a list: `lines = filehandler.readlines()` (though lines are not very useful for an html text).

Answer (score 3):

Because `urllib.urlopen` returns a file like object, you can either call `.read()` on it, or directly iterate over it.

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) for more

Edit:

Okay to explain what

> directly iterate over it

means.

```
import urllib
request = urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
for source_line in request:
    print source_line
```

Comment: The docs may have the worst notation ever (Compared to cplusplus.com and MSDN).

Comment: @georgemano they just seem more descriptive and easier to follow, the MSDN docs for example seem to jump around all over the place.

Comment: what do you mean `directly iterate over it` ?

Comment: Is `request` a descriptive name? Because essentially, the variable contains a response.